# How to share build files from one github repo to anouther

Tags: git, github

Github allows user to use http://pages.github.com. Sounds good.

I want to use it to show some demo pages for some code snippets. This makes me having two repositories.

- my-username/snippet-repo
- my-username/my-username.github.io

in the `snippet-repo` there could be a built production file, based on last (buildable) changes. I want this file to be available in my `github.io` repo without explicitly copying it from one repo to another.

Anyone faced such a problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

add another remote and push like:

`git push anotherRemote master:master` instead of `git push origin master` (or 'git push' for short)

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote

Comment: Please, extend your answer: where exactly should I push? Is there might be a special folder in my `github.io` repo where to push? repo in repo? something like github.io/ext-repos/repo1; github.io/ext-repos/repo2?

Comment: you said that you have 2 repositories, I assume they both also are remote repositories, but locally you can use just 1 repository with 2 remotes, and push to both of them by your choice.